# How to create images with border radius?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an image class `.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail` which I'm trying to apply border-radius to. It won't respond to the selector though.

Here is the code I made:

```css
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="awpcp-listing- 
    excerpt $awpcpdisplayaditems 
    $isfeaturedclass" data- breakpoints-class- prefix="awpcp-listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": 
    [0,328], "small": [328,600], 
    "medium": [600,999999]}'>
  <div class="awpcp-listing- 
    excerpt-thumbnail">
    $awpcp_image_name_srccode
  </div>
  <div class="awpcp-listing- 
    excerpt-inner" style="w">
    <h4 class="awpcp-listing- 
    title">$title_link</h4>
    <div class="awpcp-listing- 
    excerpt-content">$excerpt</div>
  </div>
  <div class="awpcp-listing- 
    excerpt-extra">
    $awpcp_city_display $awpcp_state_display $awpcp_display_adviews $awpcp_display_price $awpcpextrafields
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: add your CSS code here.

Comment: it's because in your class is a space `awpcp-listing- 
excerpt-thumbnail` has to be `awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail`

Comment: @xmasterje thanks but that's just a typo

Comment: @12345 check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/c3et6z70/1/)

Comment: @xmasterje but if I use the image src code that would just affect that particular image?

Answer (score 2):

You can either change you css to select the `img` element : `.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail img{` or you can add `overflow:hidden` to your existing css styles.

And also `display:inline-block` so the `div.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail` will have the width of the image and not `100%` ( which happens by default because div is a `block` element)

```css
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail{
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```

if the image is not the only child, use this

```css
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail img{
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that worked to give a border-radius to the right hand corner and nowhere else....? See mobile https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/

Comment: Even if i do `.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:0;
}` it doesn't work

Comment: Basically i want to image to fill the top of the box with top left and right border radius..

Comment: well. i thought the image was the only child of that div. If you have other elements, change your CSS selector to `.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail  img { border-radius :.... } `

Comment: What do you mean ? Doesn't it add border-radius to the image ?

Comment: i added in my answer a snippet with the second solution. In the answer, the solution works. i would be very surprised for that not work in your project. I even wrote that style in YOUR project  ( on the link you shared ) and it works. So..........

Comment: There must be something else controlling it because as the page loads, it shows the image with border-radius for a split second, and then reverts back to as it is...

Comment: that means you have some css loading that overwrites your own stylesheet. You can try using `!important` . But this is not related to your question. You wanted to know how to add a border to an image inside a div. That's what my answer does. You can post a different question that replicates your very specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS

```
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail img{ 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```